# Am getting UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning in try catch block with async await

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-cloud-platform, graphql, es6-promise

While implementing a graphql resolver function, I ran into an `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` error. Am sending a request to classify some text and it's the classification that's throwing an error. I want to re-throw whatever error is thrown, but the error is not being caught in the catch block.

Am not `await`ing the request because I am sending two other requests with the classify request in parallel, but am `await`ing each request in a Promise.all function.

Here is the code:

```
createPost: async (
        _,
        { fields: { media, text, location } }) => {
        try {
            const firstRequest = languageClient.classifyText({
                document: {
                    content: text,
                    type: 'PLAIN_TEXT'
                }
            });
        const secondRequest = // another request
        const thirdRequest = // another request
        const result = await Promise.all([firstRequest, secondRequest, thirdRequest]);
    } catch(error) { throw error }
    
}
```

How do I handle the error properly?

Comment: `catch (error) { throw error }` acts as if you never caught at all. You want to do `catch (error) { console.error(error) }` or `catch(error) { doSomethingElse(error) }`

Comment: Hi @DemiPixel, I tried what you suggested, but am still getting the same error. I even tried putting the classification request directly in the array passed to `Promise.all` like this `Promise.all[language.classifyText({ document: { content: text, type: 'PLAIN_TEXT' } })`, but now the error got swallowed up and nothing is showing up in the console.

Comment: What are you doing in your catch? If you are trying to print to console, are you sure there's still an error?

Comment: Am printing the error to console, but am sure there's an error. The error is that the text content to be classified is to short, but am only getting this `UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning` when I assign the request to a variable first before passing to `Promise.all`

Comment: @DemiPixel, when I removed the `throw` from the `catch` block, the resolver continued executing after an error which is not what I want. I want the error to be sent in response which is what's happening when I included the `throw`.

Comment: There's no need for the try/catch then. You can remove all that. Whatever is calling createPost should use `catch` to handle the error: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/catch

Comment: @DemiPixel I've removed the try catch, and the error is propagating well after `await`ing the `classifyText` function and stopping the resolver function from continuing executing. So now, the other 2 requests will have to wait for `classifyText` to finish which is not what I want. Why is `Promise.all` not handling/throwing the error when am `await`ing it?

Answer (score 1):

Stupid me, I wrapped the `Promise.all` with an if statement, so it's not even running at all. That's the reason why am getting weird results. I just discovered this after 3 days. I'm so stupid.